# Изменить содержимое input, но не мгновенно

Tags: javascript

Суть такова, что есть input с значением, мне нужно его значение изменить с помощью js. Я знаю как это сделать, но мне нужно чтобы содержимое inputa менялось не мгновенно, а как будто человек сам пишет, то есть, с небольшой задержкой. Потому что если задержки нет, сайт не успевает заметить вообще изменений. Такое вообще возможно сделать?

Comment: "сайт не успевает заметить вообще изменений" - это что?

Comment: Вероятно сайт обрабатывает события, навроде onblur. Нужно выяснить какие и пробовать их эмитировать.

Comment: Ну я пишу скрипт для сайта. На сайте есть input со значением. Если я изменяю вручную содержимое, то на сайте где-то изменяется блок с параметром. Тут уже не важно. А вот если я скриптом меняю содержимое, то нечего не происходит. Блок с параметром не изменяется.

Comment: @Tom "Это гвоздь не от той стенки." - скриптовые изменения значения инпута не приводят к вызову обработчика.

Comment: @Igor то есть, тут ни как не сделать?

Comment: @Tom Почему **никак**? Это же Ваш скрипт. Вызывайте: `inp.value = "aaa"; $(inp).change();` или его аналог в чистом js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript.

Comment: @Igor Спасибо. Ну значит ни как) Сайт не мой, я не могу изменить его. А как изменить input не быстро - не знаю..

Comment: @Tom "не быстро"? Скорость изменений здесь абсолютно не при чем.

Comment: @Igor Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67966/discussion-between-tom-and-igor).